# Iterate through taglib property map

Tags: c++, dictionary, taglib

Good Evening,

Recently I found the [taglib](http://taglib.github.com/) library. It's a really nice one but I can't find a possibility to get the keys and values of unkown keys in a property map (in other words to iterate the map).

This code is used for getting the map:

```
TagLib::FileRef file(file_path);
TagLib::PropertyMap map = file.tag()->properties();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate the same way you iterate over a standard container:

```
for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); it++) {
    // Do something with it.
}
```

The documentation shows [`PropertyMap`](http://taglib.github.com/api/classTagLib_1_1PropertyMap.html) extends [`List<T>`](http://taglib.github.com/api/classTagLib_1_1List.html#a5461a9c274eec6f5c2a628b9a077b4e6), which seems to satisfy all container requirements.

Comment: Well, you are right, but the reason seems to be wrong. In the header files it extends from Map<Key, T> which offers begin and end, not from List or StringList. I actually do not understand what that graph shows… Anyway thanks for the answer!

Comment: I believe you have a valid point. I just checked it, and the documentation diverges from the source files. Quite strange! Anyway, the solution should be the same. You have access to `it->first` (key) and `it->second` (value).